# List dependencies that are going to be part of the (shadow) JAR file

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

I'm using the latest version (`7.1.2`) of the `ShadowJar` (Gradle) plugin to build the application's JAR. I'm trying to exclude some dependencies from the resultant JAR, so I have configured the plugin like:

```
import com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins.shadow.tasks.ShadowJar

...

tasks.withType(ShadowJar) {
  final def attributes = [
    // ...all the attributes here
  ]
  dependencies {
    // Dependencies that are already provided in the lib/ folder of Apache Flink
    exclude(dependency("org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.12"))
    exclude(dependency("org.apache.flink:flink-java"))
    exclude(dependency("org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.12"))
  }
  manifest.attributes(attributes)
  mergeServiceFiles()
  minimize()
  setZip64(true)
}
```

It's not clear to me what dependencies are actually begin excluded/included — when unzipping and visually analyzing the generated ZIP file(s). I've been trying to compare the generated (ZIP) `-shadow` file with the one generated by the `distZip` task, but the `-shadow` one doesn't have a single JAR on it...only classes.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to print the **effective group of dependencies** that are going to be part of the final JAR file.

> Based on the `ShadowJar`'s [documentation](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/configuration/dependencies/#configuring-shadowed-dependencies), the default configuration is to merge all dependencies from the project's `runtimeClasspath`, but `./gradlew dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath` doesn't account for the excluded ones.

Answer (score 0):

In the shadow jar you'll find the `META-INF/maven` folder, there you'll find all the pom.xml files, each containing the dependency version.